# Deciding which properties are serialized at runtime

Tags: c#, serialization

Let's suppose I have to serialize an object of a class Car in levels e.g. Internal and Public. Some of the properties in the Public level should not be serialized as they are internal.

At this moment the 'easiest' way I can think of to achieve this is by using inheritance:

```
class CarPublic {
  public int PropX {get;set}
}

class CarInternal: CarPublic {
  public string PropY {get;set}
}
```

Then I could

```
object ToSerialize() {
 CarInternal car = GetCar();
 if( level == Level.Public ) { 
    return car as CarPublic;
 } else {
     return car;
 }
}
```

The result of the ToSerialize() is taken by a framework (I don't have 
control over) and serialized to JSON or XML.

I omitted the XML serialization attributes for simplicity.

This feels like a hack and hacks take you only so far. Is there better way (ways?) to achieve this?

I think its clear by now, but I would like to avoid writing my own serialization methods for JSON and XML.

Thanks in advance
Tymek

==EDIT

To clarify, I want to be able to serialize multiple levels:

```
class Car0 {
  public int PropA {get;set}
}

class Car1: Car0 {
  public string PropB {get;set}
}

class Car2: Car1 {
  public int PropC {get;set}
}

class Car3: Car2 {
  public string PropD {get;set}
}
```

and

```
object ToSerialize( Level level ) {
 Car3 car = GetCar();
 switch( level ) {
   case Level.Zero: return car as Car0;
   case Level.One: return car as Car1;
   case Level.Two: return car as Car3;
   case Level.Three: return car as Car4;
 }
 return null;
}
```

== Chosen approach

I marked Marc Gravell's answer as the answer, as it provides the generic information of how C# and it's 'standard' components support what I asked for.

However I think the best approach for my problem is to use proxy classes as shown above and
have the class being serialized in this multi-level pattern with methods like shown below.

```
public interface ICar {
    Car0 As0();
    Car1 As1();
    Car2 As2();
    Car3 As3();
 ...
 }
```

This allows keeping the *Car0..3* classes very simple, with only properties, to maintain and understand.

Comment: Writing custom serialization methods is the better way that I know of (and really isn't that difficult).  You have custom serialization requirements which lends itself to a custom serializer...  Is there a particular reason you don't want to go down that path?

Comment: The main reason is that I'm in a framework environment where the serialization should be done by the framework and I just return results as objects.

Comment: Can you see what other classes within this environment are doing to solve this problem then? If you are going to hack it to pieces, may as well hack it the same way as other folks have :)

Comment: Ha! I'm the first to do the 'expose properties depending on a level'.

Comment: I'd say it's time to update the serialization framework then due to new requirements :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This depends a lot on what serialization framework you are using. You mention xml and json - well, the first thing to note is that you can just decorate with:

```
[XmlIgnore]
public int PropX {get;set;}
```

or

```
[ScriptIgnore]
public int PropX {get;set;}
```

which `XmlSerializer` and `JavascriptSerializer` will respond to. If you need to make the decision on a per-instance basis, there is the `ShouldSerialize*` and `*Specified` patterns:

```
public bool ShouldSerializePropX() {
   // return true to serialize, false to omit
}
```

The above is a name-based pattern, that is used by `XmlSerializer` and others; it has a twin:

```
[XmlIgnore, Browsable(false)]
public bool PropXSpecified {
    get { /* return true to serialize, false to omit */ }
    set { /* can just drop this value - don't need to assign */ }
}
```

You don't need to do anything to wire them up - they work automatically.

Different serializers allow different patterns.

In addition, sometimes you can add things like `[XmlIgnore]` at runtime - for example via `XmlAttributeOverrides`, or the equivalent for any given serializer.

Comment: I marked this as the answer as it answers the question, but I described my chosen approach in the question itself as ==Chosen approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could decorate your Internal properties with a custom attribute indicating that they should be included (or ignored depending on your requirements) and then in your `ToSerialize` check the attribute.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class ShouldSerializeAttribute : Attribute { }
```

Then your resulting class definition would look like:

```
class Car 
{
    [ShouldSerialize]
    public int PropX {get;set}

    // This property won't be serialized because it is internal
    public int PropY { get; set; }
}
```

You `ToSerialize` would look something like:

```
object ToSerialize() 
{
    Car car = GetCar();

    foreach(PropertyInfo propInfo in car.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if(ShouldSerialize(propInfo)) 
        { 
            return car;
        }
    }
}
```

Where `ShouldSerialize` could look like:

```
internal bool ShouldSerialize(PropertyInfo propInfo)
{
    return propInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ShouldSerializeAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault() != null;
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Based on @Bill's insight in the comments. If you're looking to only serialize public attributes when `level` is `Level.Public` you can achieve that effect by reflecting on the type's properties using the `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly` flag:

```
foreach(PropertyInfo propInfo in car.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly))
```

This should return a list of the properties declared only by the current instance of `car`.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.  He needs to serialize a different set of properties based on the level required, not only serialize if public.

Comment: @Bill - Where in the question does it say that (or did it say that when I answered)? The code the OP posted would not achieve this so what makes you think that it is what they want? Unless I've midread the intention of the code.

Comment: @M In his code, he returns either CarInternal (all of the properties get serialized) or CarPublic (only the public properties get serialized).  See his ToSerialize method which makes the choice based on Level.Public.

Comment: @Bill - You might be right (I oversimplified the situation because I didn't consider that as a possibility). I'll update accordingly.