# How to hide a property into a base class for XML serialization

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, subclass

Let I've a base class

```
public class MyClass
{
    private bool _success;
    public bool Success
    {
        get { return _success; }
        set { _success = value; }
    }
}
```

and a derived class

```
public class MySubClass : MyClass
{
    public string str { get; set; }
}
```

**Question:** How can I to serialize `MySubClass` to `XML` such that there is no `<Success>` tag in the serialization result?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
[XmlIgnore]
public bool Success
{
    get { return _success; }
    set { _success = value; }
}
```

The `[XmlIgnore]` attribute tells the serialization process to ignore this attribute.
It will never be serialized so there won't be a node in your serialized XML

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmlignore.aspx

To ignore the field only in your subclass, you can override the property from the baseclass.

In your base class (note the `virtual` keyword):

```
public virtual bool Success {get;set;}
```

In you subclass

```
[XmlIgnore]
public override bool Success {get;set;}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I want to hide the `<Success>` when the MySubClass is serializating only. Is it possible to do?

Comment: I have been working in software for almost two decades and yet Stackoverflow never ceases to amaze me with incredibly short solutions.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have access to your base class, you can add a `ShouldSerializePropertyName` method to your class.

```
public bool ShouldSerializeSuccess()
{
    return false;
}
```

By convention XmlSerializer will execute any ShouldSerialize... method to determine if the property should be serialized. You can even do something conditionally:

```
// this will serialize sucess only if it is true.
public bool ShouldSerializeSuccess()
{
    return Sucess;
}
public bool ShouldSerializeName()
{
    return !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Name) && !Name.Equals("Default");
}
```

Comment: That depends on which method you use to serialize JSON. I belive the `JavascriptSerializer` from `System.Web.Script.Serialization (System.Web.Extensions.dll)` namespace knows about the ShouldSerialize(...) convention: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9273144/98491