# Hide boolean if false in XmlSerialization in C#

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I am serializing a class, which has a `boolean` parameter. I want to hide this parameter if it has value `false`. Below is the class-

```
public class UserPreferences
{
    [XmlAttributeAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name;

    [XmlAttributeAttribute("SaveOnClose")]
    public bool SaveOnClose;

    public UserPreferences() { }

    public UserPreferences(string Name)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
    }

    public UserPreferences(string Name, bool SaveOnClose)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.SaveOnClose = SaveOnClose;
    }
}
```

Below is the main method-

```
UserPreferences userPreferences = new UserPreferences("guest");
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(UserPreferences));
serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, userPreferences);
```

Below is the output of this code-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="IBM437"?>
<UserPreferences xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Name="guest" SaveOnClose="false" />
```

Notice that the parameter `SaveOnClose` is false. Is it possible to hide this parameter in this case? Since `false` is considered as default value here.

Also If this parameter is hidden and I deserialize the above XML,  parameter `SaveOnClose` should be assumed as `false`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deciding which properties are serialized at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271962/deciding-which-properties-are-serialized-at-runtime)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Add a method ShouldSerializeSaveOnClose() and let it return false if the property SaveOnClose should not be serialized.

```
public bool ShouldSerializeSaveOnClose() {  
     return SaveOnClose == true;  
 }
```

Or, instead of adding a method you can also add a property Specified.
Also, add an XmlIgnore attribute on that property to prevent that it gets serialized.

```
[XmlIgnore]
public bool SaveOnCloseSpecified
{
   get { return SaveOnClose == true; }
}
```

Comment: Two points- (1) The last method doesn't have any return data type. Please change it to `public bool SaveOnCloseSpecified` (2) Will it give me `false` for property which is hidden, if I deserialize this generated XML?

Comment: You forgot to mention an important fact to understand correctly: the relation between `SaveOnClose` and `SaveOnCloseSpecified` is made automatically by naming convention, because the suffix `Specified` is added to the property name.

Answer (score 5):

Try the code below:  when you specify the 2nd argument in constructor, the attribute is returned in xml. else its hidden.

```
private bool hasDefaultValue = false;

[XmlAttributeAttribute("Name")]
public string Name;

[XmlAttribute("SaveOnClose")]
public bool SaveOnClose;

[XmlIgnore]
public bool SaveOnCloseSpecified
{
    get { return hasDefaultValue; }
}

public UserPreferences() { }

public UserPreferences(string Name)
{
    this.Name = Name;
}

public UserPreferences(string Name, bool SaveOnClose)
{
    this.Name = Name;
    this.SaveOnClose = SaveOnClose;
    hasDefaultValue = true;
}
```

when you have new UserPreferences("guest",false);
you should get output as

```
<UserPreferences ... Name="guest" SaveOnClose="false" />
```

for new UserPreferences("guest",true);
you should get output as

```
<UserPreferences ... Name="guest" SaveOnClose="true" />
```

for new UserPreferences("guest")
you should get output as

```
<UserPreferences ... Name="guest">
```